# How to set up Parcel bundling in a Chrome extension for the whole source directory?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, parceljs

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension.

However, once I've tried integrating Parcel I am in a bit of a pickle. I'd like to use Parcel for compatibility with old Chrome versions + for splitting my code into multiple files.

#### My folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

#### When I try to make this command work:

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build src/js/script.js", }
```

I end up only with the 'script.js' inside the '/dist' folder, **but I want to create a dist folder that I can package and publish**. I basically want to get all my html, css, js (etc.) inside a dist folder. Can this be done?

How would you go about adding a whole framework, like Vue or React e.g. to make the popup or options page?

Comment: Have you tried visiting these related threads: [Support WebExtensions manifest.json](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1039), [WebExtension Support](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/1484)

Comment: I tried the [parcel-plugin-web-extension](https://github.com/kevincharm/parcel-plugin-web-extension) mentioned in there. It's not production ready.

Answer (score 3):

Parcel 2 has a first-party [WebExtensions transformer](https://parceljs.org/recipes/web-extension/). It will pick up every files mentioned in `manifest.json` plus some other files like what's under `_locales` and it works fairly well!

`.parcelrc` file:

```json
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-webextension"
}
```

Install command:

```sh
npm install parcel @parcel/config-webextension
```

Build command:

```sh
parcel build manifest.json

✨ Built in 1.18s
```